# Countif Cell and Cell to the Right

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to count how many times a cell in a row and the cell to the right equals something.

```
=countif(2:2,"=A"&1+"=B")
```

[image]

If row 2 has an "A" in column E and a "B" in column F (the column to the Right) then count that.
But if column J has an "A" and column K has a "C" then DON'T count that.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need something of this kind:

```
=countifs(A2:Y2,"A",B2:Z2,"B")
```